# Dynamic loading FBX in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to load an already created FBX object into the scene at runtime

My code here

```
void Start()
{
    string url = "http://everyday3d.com/unity3d/obj/monkey.obj";
    StartCoroutine(DownloadAssetBundle<GameObject>("monkey", url, 1));
}


public IEnumerator DownloadAssetBundle<T>(string asset, string url, int version) where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (url, version))
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error != null)
            throw new Exception(www.error);
        AssetBundle assetBundle = www.assetBundle;

        var Object = assetBundle.LoadAsset(asset, typeof(T));
        Instantiate(Object);
        assetBundle.Unload(false);
    }
}
```

And i have error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Loader+<DownloadAssetBundle>c__Iterator0`1[UnityEngine.GameObject].MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/Loader.cs:24)
```

I found out for what it is, because www.assetBundle == null
Any ideas for solving this problem have? Reading the forum I realized that my code such as normal.

Comment: ulr for example, im trying to use file:///C:/test.FBX

Comment: its because your code is obviously for downloading an asset bundle, not an individual asset, as you are trying to do. Also an `.obj` is not an `.fbx`

Comment: Unity's [asset bundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) are a very specific type of pre-built file. You don't appear to be loading the correct file type for the operations you're using.

Comment: Okey, how can I solve my problem? Loading models of the project is to builded? many thx

Answer (score 0):

its because your code is obviously for downloading an asset bundle, not an individual asset, as you are trying to do. Also an `.obj` is not an `.fbx`

Have you tried just:

```
WWW www = new WWW ("http://everyday3d.com/unity3d/obj/monkey.obj");
yield return www;
```